# Function that returns string to main function C++

Tags: c++

im new to C++.

I want to get a string with std::cin and call it in the main and print it with std::cout.

I already tried a few things but it didn't work for me.
The last method I tried was this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    

string person(string personname)
{
    std::cin >> personname;
    return personname;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << person();    
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the function's parameter? Parameters are used to transmit information into a function, and this function does not need any information from the outside. Read about local variables in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: That will not even compile. remove parameter `personname` from the function `person` and you are good to go.

Comment: Almost good to go :). Define `personename` in `person()`. And remove `using namespace std;` - you don't use it.

Comment: The point of a parameter is to pass information into the function. If the first thing the function does is replace that information, then the parameter isn't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a function that does not exist. The function you've provided is

```
  string person(string name);
```

but the function you're calling is `person()` which does not has any definition available. What you can do is remove the parameter in function `person`.

```
string person(){ 
   string name; 
   cin >> name; 
   return name;
}
```

now when you call this in `main()` it will work

```
int main(){
    cout<<person()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personname should be a local variable within the person function not a parameter because you don't pass any values to `person` in the main function. This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string person(){
  string personname;
  std::cin >> personname;
  return personname;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << person();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first advice would be learn about pass by value, pointer and reference in C++ then everything will be clear for you. Now try with below:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    

void person(string &personname)
{
    std::cin >> personname;
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    person(name);
    std::cout << name;   
}
```

Comment: -ve voter please explain what wrong in it? It will help me to improve my answer in future.

Comment: What about `string name; person(name); std::cout << name;` ? Note: that's not an explaination for the downvote, since I didn't downvote, but the reason might be this.

Comment: @scopchanov, Thanks :-). corrected.

Comment: Why pass in by reference only to return a copy? You either end up with two versions of the same string or a needless copy.

Comment: @Galik, you're right. In my comment I did address that, but I've suggested a change only in `main()`. So, `person()` could be made `void` and the `return` won't be necessary.

Comment: @Galik, Thanks for pointing at my mistake. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Strings just don't work like that if you want to get a string from user you should use loops or use some pre-defined functions for example "gets()" .
actually the code you wrote kind of works!however you have to first declare your string which you've named "personname".without declaring it your code is meaningless
here is the code you should use
warning: this code doesn't return whatever you write after space.If you want to be able to get after space characters you can use arrays and gets() function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    
string personname ;
string person(){
      cin >> personname;
      return personname;
}
main(){
cout << person();    
getch();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    

string person()
{
    string personname;
    std::cin >> personname;
    return personname;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << person();    
}
```

The variable was not declared within the function, you also created the function by passing a parameter that you did not send when you called it.

Comment: The same code was already given by @blazgrom. If you agree with him - upvote, don't repeat it.

Comment: Probably comment at the same time? When I answered, there were no previous answers.

Comment: Could be. The answers are only 3 minutes apart. Besides the other one was removed.